# Apache showing PHP code - after upgrade on Mac to macOS Sierra

Tags: php

I'm using an iMac which I've just updated to macOS Sierra. Prior to this it was running El Capitan.

Under my El Capitan set up I had Apache, PHP and MySQL [configured as per this guide](https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/get-apache-mysql-php-and-phpmyadmin-working-on-osx-10-11-el-capitan/). This worked without any problems.

When I updated to Sierra it overwrote a load of config files. So I went back through the guide and configured everything as I had under El Capitan.

`http://localhost` is working as I'd expect and I can see files in my webroot. However, if I open a PHP page, it just shows the raw PHP code rather than executing it.

I'm using the following:

#### Apache

- **Server version**: Apache/2.4.23 (Unix)
- **Server built**:   Aug  8 2016 16:31:34

#### PHP

- PHP 7.0.10 (cli) (built: Aug 31 2016 10:25:51) ( NTS )

#### macOS

- Sierra 10.12

Comment: Try looking for error messages in an apache log file, probably in `/private/var/log/apache2/`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Sierra comes with PHP 5, not PHP 7. Anyway, check if the module is loaded in `httpd.conf`:

```
LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so
```

If this doesn't work, probably you didn't told Apache to recognize *.php files as php executables. To do so, locate and edit `httpd.conf` and add the following lines (if not already present):

```
<FilesMatch .php$>
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

and edit the `DirectoryIndex` parameter:

```
<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
</IfModule>
```

Another common solution is to activate the short open tags (if you have any in your PHP code). Locate `php.ini`, search for the string `short_open_tag = Off` and change it to `short_open_tag = On`.

Restart Apache.

Comment: In my case, 

it was showing plain php code through virtual host. after uncommented the specific module
"LoadModule php7_module libexec/apache2/libphp7.so"

 in /etc/apache2/httpd.conf path the problem is gone.

Answer (score 3):

Your apache isn't processing php files any more. There is line

```
LoadModule **php5_module** libexec/apache2/**libphp5.so**
```

in your config file `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf`

But you have installed PHP7. Change it to:

```
LoadModule **php7_module** libexec/apache2/**libphp7.so**
```

or maybe modules/mod_php.so or whenever  php module is located.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work.  Syntax error on line 170 of /private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf: Cannot load libexec/apache2/libphp7.so into server: dlopen(/usr/libexec/apache2/libphp7.so, 10): image not found

Comment: Hmm this is working for me, surprised, how PHP version updated to 5-7 in my mac, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Ensure the `#LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so` line is uncommented in the main `httpd.conf` file. Don't forget to restart Apache `sudo apachectl restart`.

Comment: I tried this already. That line is definitely uncommented and I restarted Apache. Also did a 'configtest' and it's saying the Syntax is OK.

Comment: Gets even stranger but if I add "AddType application/x-httpd-php .php" to /etc/apache2/httpd.conf and restart Apache it processes PHP. But it's using PHP 5.x instead of 7.x (??!)

Comment: The config line in Andy's comment fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score -1):

I had this problem as well. Check your /private/ect/apache2/extra/htttpd-vhosts.conf to see if still has your virtual hosts settings. My original one was renamed to httpd-vhosts.conf~previous.

Comment: I did a 'diff' and the files are exactly the same.

Comment: Can you navigate to a non-php page?

Comment: yes it will load any page requested. It's just that .php scripts show the  PHP code (as source code/text) rather than executing it.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot open the .php file using open file from the browsers File menu,
You have to type localhost/info.php(or whatever file and path you're trying to open) in your browsers address bar...
This works for me at least.
Hope you work it out.

Comment: In my case, 

it was showing plain php code through virtual host. after uncommented the specific module
"LoadModule php7_module libexec/apache2/libphp7.so"

 in /etc/apache2/httpd.conf path the problem is gone.