# Why is Apache using a version of PHP I don't have?

Tags: macos, apache-http-server, php

I've recently had difficulties with Apache not processing PHP files on my Mac after upgrading to macOS Sierra. Original post about it [is here](https://superuser.com/questions/1129654/apache-showing-php-code-after-upgrade-on-mac-to-macos-sierra).

The way in which I "fixed" this problem was to add the following to `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf`

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
```

I then restarted Apache `sudo apachectl restart` and my PHP scripts were processed.

However, when I run a `phpinfo()` script it's saying **PHP Version 5.6.24**

When I run PHP from a command line, it's reporting **PHP 7.0.10** (which is what I expect and want).

It gets stranger because I don't know where PHP 5.6.24 even exists on my system. If I run

```
which php
```

It gives:

```
/usr/local/php5/bin/php
```

But examining this further, that appears to be a symbolic link to PHP 7:

```
$ cd /usr/local
$ ls -l
lrwxr-xr-x 1 root  wheel 38 14 Sep 11:18 php5 -> /usr/local/php5-7.0.10-20160831-102733
```

Executing PHP directly from `/usr/local/php5-7.0.10-20160831-102733` also reports PHP 7:

```
$ pwd
/usr/local/php5-7.0.10-20160831-102733/bin
$ ./php -v
PHP 7.0.10
```

How do I get Apache to use PHP 7.x, and more importantly, where is PHP 5.x on my system that it's running?

Answer (score -2):

php can be built in various variants. There is at least a command line variant, a cgi variant, a fastcgi variant and an apache module.

You need to build a php 7 apache module, then reconfigure apache to use it.

http://php.net/manual/en/install.unix.apache2.php

Comment: "You need to build a php 7 apache module" - How do you do this specifically? "You then reconfigure apache to use it." - How is this done?

Comment: If you are building both apache and php from source then the details are at the link I gave. If you use apache from some sort of package then you will have to figure out how to install the file needed to build modules within that specific packaging system.